# How to refactor PHP to help improve SQL Server speed?

Tags: php, sql-server

I've been tasked with finding a solution to some performance issues we've been having with our PHP web application (basically, we're reaching a "failure" point when combining high-volume users with peak traffic/load hours). What I've found so far is that the bottleneck is occurring when trying to access the MS SQL Server database. Our sysadmin suggested that it's probably due to SQL Server having to do too much context switching, because of the amount that the code queries the database.

Upon looking more into context switching and how to reduce it, though, I've only been able to find vague mentions of how to actually do so at the application code level, mostly along the lines of "refactor your code so it doesn't make so many calls," or .Net-specific tips.

We're dealing with a large, complex codebase, so we can't do things like completely rewrite the system, and we also have pretty well optimized (as best we could) the individual queries that we can, so what other refactoring opportunities can we look for to help make our code not bring our database server to its knees?

I don't currently know the full stats on our database server, but it's beefy enough to run MS SQL Server 2008 and was doing well until recently.

ETA: I'm simply a developer and don't have any authoritative power, so I can't do things like hire consultants. While I'm willing to make the suggestion to my superiors, I'm primarily looking for things that we can do in-house to further work toward solving the underlying issue.

As I explained in a comment, I understand that the context switching is more a symptom of something else, which is then causing the issues we're actually seeing (slow responses from the database; just like in an OS, doing a lot of swapping results in slow response from an application, but is itself a symptom of other things taking up too much RAM). What is causing the context switching? A lot of database access from the application code. The problem is, the individual queries are already as good as we can get them right now, as indicated by our monitoring software, so what else can we do to help this problem?

My admin's use of context switching has since been clarified. It seems that the issue, given his clarification, is that there are a lot of relatively small calls being made, which would require the database server to enqueue them as it handles each one in turn, driving up the response time as the scripts wait for their requested data. Are there any strategies, then, for combining these database calls, or otherwise adjusting how an MVC-structured PHP application makes calls to the database so that the scripts aren't constantly waiting on the database?

Comment: Have you considered utilizing a caching technology so that you aren't reading from the DB every time a request is made?  If the content isn't changing that frequently, then you can drastically drop the number of SQL requests that way.

Comment: @Dameo - Unfortunately, I'm pretty certain a lot of data does change quite a bit, due to the nature of the application. I'll have to check with the admins, but I think it's caching what it can, already. A lot of the really major slowdowns are in things that can't really be cached, such as searches (which are generally done with AJAX calls), but are starting to affect other areas when they have to refresh their content from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a SQL Server performance problem, approach it as a SQL Server performance troubleshooting. There are some well known methodologies like [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx). The SQL Server [Performance Troubleshooting Flowchart](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/presentations/archive/2008/04/18/troubleshooting-sql-server-2005-2008-performance-and-scalability-flowchart.aspx) is a great syntheses of the various articles, tools, methodologies and metrics at your disposal to identify the bottleneck.

Saying that the problem is 'context switching' is non-informative, unhelpful and unactionable.  For the record, there is not even such concept as 'context switching' in SQL Server troubleshooting because of the very specific way [SQL Server scheduling architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189267%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) works. This is not how SQL Server performance troubleshooting is done, it is not even close to true root cause analysis. You need to identify the problem before you can attempt a solution. If your admin cannot help you, seek specialized help from qualified consultants.

And yes, if you can cache anything in the client and avoid querying the server is always, by definition, good. If the client and proxies can cache the page and avoid even hitting your HTTP server, is even better. These are true with any technology stack.

> there are a lot of relatively small calls being made, which would
>   require the database server to enqueue them as it handles each one in
>   turn, driving up the response time as the scripts wait for their
>   requested data. Are there any strategies, then, for combining these
>   database calls

There is no silver bullet. Consider though that a well tuned database can drive **a lot** of small requests per second (many thousands per second) w/o problems. Did you measure metrics in:

- [SQL Server, Databases Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189883%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [SQL Server, Transactions Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189038%28v=sql.105%29)
- [SQL Server, Wait Statistics Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190732%28v=sql.105%29)
- [SQL Server, General Statistics Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190697%28v=sql.105%29)
- [SQL Server, Access Methods Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177426%28v=sql.105%29)
- [SQL Server, Buffer Manager Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189628%28v=sql.105%29)

*These* are interesting metrics that can tell a lot where you should focus your effort.

Comment: Context switching is a concept in SQL Server (and therefore, is "such a concept" in troubleshooting, even if tangentially), but it's a *symptom* that then causes other problems. Making a large number of simple queries increases the number of times per second SQL Server context switches, for example, and doing that slows everything in general down. The question then becomes, if the individual queries are as optimized as they can be right now, what else can the dev team do to help with the performance issue aside from the generic "look at your monitoring software"?

Comment: SQL Server is a cooperative multitasking user mode model that doesn't really do 'context switching'. SQL Server worker threads yield intentionally and a large number of simple queries causes pending tasks increase, not thread contention. What you need to focus is to investigate the SQL Server performance issues using SQL Server methodology, focusing on wait statistics, buffer pool utilization, query plans etc. The links in my answer are starting points to the investigation you need to do. There is no silver bullet.

Comment: As a side note: the closest think to context switching problem in SQL Server is CPU saturation, ie. driving SQL server to 100% cpu w/o no other bottleneck. There can be cases when this is the *correct* behavior, ie. you really managed to drive 100% CPU out of it and get the higher throughput it can give (think TPC benchmarks). To achieve that is * extremely* difficult and the IO hardware must be exquisite (capable of thousands of IOPS for each core at SQL disposal).

Comment: Almost always the alternative is that 100% CPU is caused by bad queries, mostly by large table scans (ie. the system drives 100% CPU because is constantly walking many GBs or buffer pool RAM). The troubleshooting methodologies mentioned in my links will quickly point out the issue and possibly single out the query or table causing the problem (could be a bad query, a missing index, outdated stats etc).

Comment: Thank you for the info. As I mentioned, the admin brought the idea up, and things like this article: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2012/01/12/performance-impact-driving-up-context-switches-sec.aspx reinforced the idea. That said, my admin clarified what he meant, "SQL might be a slow down depending on how groups are built thus creating a lot of waits on the web side. I wondered, if there were a heap of calls back and forth between apps that may contribute to slow downs due to the simple act of having to spin processes up and down all over to accommodate."

Comment: Linchi's article is actually quite bad a resource. He simply manipulates the metric, w/o understanding what he does or why he observes that results (he himself admits as much). I strongly urge you to follow SQL Server methodologies.

Comment: Just to give you an idea what can produce a result like Linchi observed: hardware that defers all network card interrupts to a specific socket/core. Modern machines do a much better job at it. On these older machines high number of small network packets create a load that is dominated by high CPU privileged time and high context switching, indeed, w/o the workload being able to drive the machine 100% CPU on all cores. This is quite hard to alleviate in application (it requires batching many requests in few calls and no ORM supports it) but easily fixed by switch to newer hardware.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain! :) We're not using an ORM, so that's not a hurdle for us, and if you have any resources on request batching, I'd love to look at them. I've passed on the resources you've provided on the database stuff to my DBA, but I'd still love to have resources for all fronts in this, since, as you mentioned, there's no silver bullet.

Comment: Basically it boils down to this: instead of sending 10 individual requests `insert into ... values ...`, send 1 requests with 10 INSERT statements. Simple in theory, very difficult in practice.